# File Geodatabase dependency missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gis, arcgis

I am using File Geodatabase API into my own MFC C++ application (which only reads data from .gdb folders). I have included all the headers and libraries required for the api in the project Properties section. (except FileGDBAPI.dll and FileGDBAPID.dll files because I don't know the including directory for them). There is no compile time error but when I create any object from FileGDBAPI (e.g GeoDatabase geodatabase;), I am getting an error

> "the appliaction was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
>   . Click OK to close the application"

Can someone please tell me what I am ignoring or anything that can make this error go away. How can I add *.dll files related to File Geodatabase API?

Comment: That error is indicative of a mismatch between your application and the dlls you are trying to use.  Are they both built for the same platform (32 bit? 64 bit?)

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive is an [NTSATUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) code. The symbolic constant for `0xC000007B` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`, with the accompanying error message:

> {Bad Image}
>   %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.

This error is usually raised, when a 32-bit application tries to load a 64-bit DLL or vice versa.

To solve this issue you have to copy the DLLs with **matching bitness** to the application directory. If you compile for 64-bit, you have to copy the 64-bit DLLs, if you are compiling for 32-bit, use the 32-bit DLLs.